# Single Value Decomposition implementation C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv

Who can recommend a stable and correct implementation Single Value Decomposition (SVD) in C++? Preferably standalone implementation (would not want to add large library for one method).

I use OpenCV... but openCV SVD returns different decompositions(!) for a single matrix. I understand, that exists more than one decomposition of simple matrix... but why openCV do like that? random basis? or what?

This instability causes the error in my calculations in some cases, and I can't understand why. **However**, the results are returned by mathlab or wolframalpha - **always** give correct calculations ....

Comment: At the danger of outing myself as dumb: What is "SVD"??

Comment: SVD = singular value decomposition.  @sbi, not knowing this doesn't make you dumb, it's kind of specialist stuff.  Of course, those of us who do know what it means feel unjustifiably smart :-)

Comment: So common - closed questions have most up-votes...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can't find a stand-alone implementation, you might try the [eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php) which does SVD . It is pretty large, however it is template-only so you only have a compile-time dependency.

Comment: is this one correct?

Answer (score 19):

Try [redsvd](http://code.google.com/p/redsvd/) (BSD license). It implements clean and **very efficient**, [modern algorithms for SVD](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~jtropp/papers/HMT11-Finding-Structure-SIREV.pdf), including partial (truncated) SVD.

Redsvd is built on top of the beautiful C++ templating library, [eigen3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=3.0). Since you mention installing is an issue, you'll like to hear eigen3 requires no installation. It's just templates (C++ header files).

Also, there don't exist "more than one decomposition of a single matrix". The SVD decomposition always exists and is unique, up to flipping signs of the corresponding `U`/`V` vectors.

Comment: In general case SVD decomposition is not unique. One must ensure that all singular values are different, then the decomposition is defined up to sign of U or V vectors as you stated.

Comment: redsvd uses [Eigen3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org), the latest version of which is licensed under MPL2. [RedSVD-h](https://github.com/ntessore/redsvd-h) also uses Eigen3.

Comment: does it do all these things ?

Answer (score 9):

A standalone, templated implementation of SVD is available in the PVFMM library (See file: include/mat_utils.txx).
The library is open source and is hosted on GitHub.
It is also available for download from the University of Texas website:
http://padas.ices.utexas.edu/software/

It is Algorithm1 in: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/inderjit/public_papers/HLA_SVD.pdf
(Computation of the Singular Value Decomposition, Alan Kaylor Cline, Inderjit S. Dhillon)

I implemented it for computing SVD in quadruple precision. My implementation is not very efficient since I only need it for offline pre-computation.

The function `svd` uses the interface for `dgesvd` in LAPACK, with JOBU='S' and JOBVT='S',
with the exception that the singular values are not sorted.

This code is available free without warranty of any kind.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#define U(i,j) U_[(i)*dim[0]+(j)]
#define S(i,j) S_[(i)*dim[1]+(j)]
#define V(i,j) V_[(i)*dim[1]+(j)]

template <class T>
void GivensL(T* S_, const size_t dim[2], size_t m, T a, T b){
  T r=sqrt(a*a+b*b);
  T c=a/r;
  T s=-b/r;

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(size_t i=0;i<dim[1];i++){
    T S0=S(m+0,i);
    T S1=S(m+1,i);
    S(m  ,i)+=S0*(c-1);
    S(m  ,i)+=S1*(-s );

    S(m+1,i)+=S0*( s );
    S(m+1,i)+=S1*(c-1);
  }
}

template <class T>
void GivensR(T* S_, const size_t dim[2], size_t m, T a, T b){
  T r=sqrt(a*a+b*b);
  T c=a/r;
  T s=-b/r;

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(size_t i=0;i<dim[0];i++){
    T S0=S(i,m+0);
    T S1=S(i,m+1);
    S(i,m  )+=S0*(c-1);
    S(i,m  )+=S1*(-s );

    S(i,m+1)+=S0*( s );
    S(i,m+1)+=S1*(c-1);
  }
}

template <class T>
void SVD(const size_t dim[2], T* U_, T* S_, T* V_, T eps=-1){
  assert(dim[0]>=dim[1]);

  { // Bi-diagonalization
    size_t n=std::min(dim[0],dim[1]);
    std::vector<T> house_vec(std::max(dim[0],dim[1]));
    for(size_t i=0;i<n;i++){
      // Column Householder
      {
        T x1=S(i,i);
        if(x1<0) x1=-x1;

        T x_inv_norm=0;
        for(size_t j=i;j<dim[0];j++){
          x_inv_norm+=S(j,i)*S(j,i);
        }
        if(x_inv_norm>0) x_inv_norm=1/sqrt(x_inv_norm);

        T alpha=sqrt(1+x1*x_inv_norm);
        T beta=x_inv_norm/alpha;

        house_vec[i]=-alpha;
        for(size_t j=i+1;j<dim[0];j++){
          house_vec[j]=-beta*S(j,i);
        }
        if(S(i,i)<0) for(size_t j=i+1;j<dim[0];j++){
          house_vec[j]=-house_vec[j];
        }
      }
      #pragma omp parallel for
      for(size_t k=i;k<dim[1];k++){
        T dot_prod=0;
        for(size_t j=i;j<dim[0];j++){
          dot_prod+=S(j,k)*house_vec[j];
        }
        for(size_t j=i;j<dim[0];j++){
          S(j,k)-=dot_prod*house_vec[j];
        }
      }
      #pragma omp parallel for
      for(size_t k=0;k<dim[0];k++){
        T dot_prod=0;
        for(size_t j=i;j<dim[0];j++){
          dot_prod+=U(k,j)*house_vec[j];
        }
        for(size_t j=i;j<dim[0];j++){
          U(k,j)-=dot_prod*house_vec[j];
        }
      }

      // Row Householder
      if(i>=n-1) continue;
      {
        T x1=S(i,i+1);
        if(x1<0) x1=-x1;

        T x_inv_norm=0;
        for(size_t j=i+1;j<dim[1];j++){
          x_inv_norm+=S(i,j)*S(i,j);
        }
        if(x_inv_norm>0) x_inv_norm=1/sqrt(x_inv_norm);

        T alpha=sqrt(1+x1*x_inv_norm);
        T beta=x_inv_norm/alpha;

        house_vec[i+1]=-alpha;
        for(size_t j=i+2;j<dim[1];j++){
          house_vec[j]=-beta*S(i,j);
        }
        if(S(i,i+1)<0) for(size_t j=i+2;j<dim[1];j++){
          house_vec[j]=-house_vec[j];
        }
      }
      #pragma omp parallel for
      for(size_t k=i;k<dim[0];k++){
        T dot_prod=0;
        for(size_t j=i+1;j<dim[1];j++){
          dot_prod+=S(k,j)*house_vec[j];
        }
        for(size_t j=i+1;j<dim[1];j++){
          S(k,j)-=dot_prod*house_vec[j];
        }
      }
      #pragma omp parallel for
      for(size_t k=0;k<dim[1];k++){
        T dot_prod=0;
        for(size_t j=i+1;j<dim[1];j++){
          dot_prod+=V(j,k)*house_vec[j];
        }
        for(size_t j=i+1;j<dim[1];j++){
          V(j,k)-=dot_prod*house_vec[j];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  size_t k0=0;
  if(eps<0){
    eps=1.0;
    while(eps+(T)1.0>1.0) eps*=0.5;
    eps*=64.0;
  }
  while(k0<dim[1]-1){ // Diagonalization
    T S_max=0.0;
    for(size_t i=0;i<dim[1];i++) S_max=(S_max>S(i,i)?S_max:S(i,i));

    while(k0<dim[1]-1 && fabs(S(k0,k0+1))<=eps*S_max) k0++;
    if(k0==dim[1]-1) continue;

    size_t n=k0+2;
    while(n<dim[1] && fabs(S(n-1,n))>eps*S_max) n++;

    T alpha=0;
    T beta=0;
    { // Compute mu
      T C[2][2];
      C[0][0]=S(n-2,n-2)*S(n-2,n-2);
      if(n-k0>2) C[0][0]+=S(n-3,n-2)*S(n-3,n-2);
      C[0][1]=S(n-2,n-2)*S(n-2,n-1);
      C[1][0]=S(n-2,n-2)*S(n-2,n-1);
      C[1][1]=S(n-1,n-1)*S(n-1,n-1)+S(n-2,n-1)*S(n-2,n-1);

      T b=-(C[0][0]+C[1][1])/2;
      T c=  C[0][0]*C[1][1] - C[0][1]*C[1][0];
      T d=0;
      if(b*b-c>0) d=sqrt(b*b-c);
      else{
        T b=(C[0][0]-C[1][1])/2;
        T c=-C[0][1]*C[1][0];
        if(b*b-c>0) d=sqrt(b*b-c);
      }

      T lambda1=-b+d;
      T lambda2=-b-d;

      T d1=lambda1-C[1][1]; d1=(d1<0?-d1:d1);
      T d2=lambda2-C[1][1]; d2=(d2<0?-d2:d2);
      T mu=(d1<d2?lambda1:lambda2);

      alpha=S(k0,k0)*S(k0,k0)-mu;
      beta=S(k0,k0)*S(k0,k0+1);
    }

    for(size_t k=k0;k<n-1;k++)
    {
      size_t dimU[2]={dim[0],dim[0]};
      size_t dimV[2]={dim[1],dim[1]};
      GivensR(S_,dim ,k,alpha,beta);
      GivensL(V_,dimV,k,alpha,beta);

      alpha=S(k,k);
      beta=S(k+1,k);
      GivensL(S_,dim ,k,alpha,beta);
      GivensR(U_,dimU,k,alpha,beta);

      alpha=S(k,k+1);
      beta=S(k,k+2);
    }

    { // Make S bi-diagonal again
      for(size_t i0=k0;i0<n-1;i0++){
        for(size_t i1=0;i1<dim[1];i1++){
          if(i0>i1 || i0+1<i1) S(i0,i1)=0;
        }
      }
      for(size_t i0=0;i0<dim[0];i0++){
        for(size_t i1=k0;i1<n-1;i1++){
          if(i0>i1 || i0+1<i1) S(i0,i1)=0;
        }
      }
      for(size_t i=0;i<dim[1]-1;i++){
        if(fabs(S(i,i+1))<=eps*S_max){
          S(i,i+1)=0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

#undef U
#undef S
#undef V

template<class T>
inline void svd(char *JOBU, char *JOBVT, int *M, int *N, T *A, int *LDA,
    T *S, T *U, int *LDU, T *VT, int *LDVT, T *WORK, int *LWORK,
    int *INFO){
  assert(*JOBU=='S');
  assert(*JOBVT=='S');
  const size_t dim[2]={std::max(*N,*M), std::min(*N,*M)};
  T* U_=new T[dim[0]*dim[0]]; memset(U_, 0, dim[0]*dim[0]*sizeof(T));
  T* V_=new T[dim[1]*dim[1]]; memset(V_, 0, dim[1]*dim[1]*sizeof(T));
  T* S_=new T[dim[0]*dim[1]];

  const size_t lda=*LDA;
  const size_t ldu=*LDU;
  const size_t ldv=*LDVT;

  if(dim[1]==*M){
    for(size_t i=0;i<dim[0];i++)
    for(size_t j=0;j<dim[1];j++){
      S_[i*dim[1]+j]=A[i*lda+j];
    }
  }else{
    for(size_t i=0;i<dim[0];i++)
    for(size_t j=0;j<dim[1];j++){
      S_[i*dim[1]+j]=A[j*lda+i];
    }
  }
  for(size_t i=0;i<dim[0];i++){
    U_[i*dim[0]+i]=1;
  }
  for(size_t i=0;i<dim[1];i++){
    V_[i*dim[1]+i]=1;
  }

  SVD<T>(dim, U_, S_, V_, (T)-1);

  for(size_t i=0;i<dim[1];i++){ // Set S
    S[i]=S_[i*dim[1]+i];
  }
  if(dim[1]==*M){ // Set U
    for(size_t i=0;i<dim[1];i++)
    for(size_t j=0;j<*M;j++){
      U[j+ldu*i]=V_[j+i*dim[1]]*(S[i]<0.0?-1.0:1.0);
    }
  }else{
    for(size_t i=0;i<dim[1];i++)
    for(size_t j=0;j<*M;j++){
      U[j+ldu*i]=U_[i+j*dim[0]]*(S[i]<0.0?-1.0:1.0);
    }
  }
  if(dim[0]==*N){ // Set V
    for(size_t i=0;i<*N;i++)
    for(size_t j=0;j<dim[1];j++){
      VT[j+ldv*i]=U_[j+i*dim[0]];
    }
  }else{
    for(size_t i=0;i<*N;i++)
    for(size_t j=0;j<dim[1];j++){
      VT[j+ldv*i]=V_[i+j*dim[1]];
    }
  }
  for(size_t i=0;i<dim[1];i++){
    S[i]=S[i]*(S[i]<0.0?-1.0:1.0);
  }

  delete[] U_;
  delete[] S_;
  delete[] V_;
  *INFO=0;
}

int main(){
  typedef double Real_t;
  int n1=45, n2=27;

  // Create matrix
  Real_t* M =new Real_t[n1*n2];
  for(size_t i=0;i<n1*n2;i++) M[i]=drand48();

  int m = n2;
  int n = n1;
  int k = (m<n?m:n);
  Real_t* tU =new Real_t[m*k];
  Real_t* tS =new Real_t[k];
  Real_t* tVT=new Real_t[k*n];

  { // Compute SVD
    int INFO=0;
    char JOBU  = 'S';
    char JOBVT = 'S';
    int wssize = 3*(m<n?m:n)+(m>n?m:n);
    int wssize1 = 5*(m<n?m:n);
    wssize = (wssize>wssize1?wssize:wssize1);
    Real_t* wsbuf = new Real_t[wssize];
    svd(&JOBU, &JOBVT, &m, &n, &M[0], &m, &tS[0], &tU[0], &m, &tVT[0], &k, wsbuf, &wssize, &INFO);
    delete[] wsbuf;
  }

  { // Check Error
    Real_t max_err=0;
    for(size_t i0=0;i0<m;i0++)
    for(size_t i1=0;i1<n;i1++){
      Real_t E=M[i1*m+i0];
      for(size_t i2=0;i2<k;i2++) E-=tU[i2*m+i0]*tS[i2]*tVT[i1*k+i2];
      if(max_err<fabs(E)) max_err=fabs(E);
    }
    std::cout<<max_err<<'\n';
  }

  delete[] tU;
  delete[] tS;
  delete[] tVT;
  delete[] M;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Jason, that can be said about the links to any of the other libraries. I do not have any plans to remove the project from GitHub. The link to the paper describing the algorithm is only additional information.

Comment: You could improve your answer with sample code.  FYI, someone else flagged this post as low quality.  The old answers in this thread also relatively low quality, but it is easier to attention on low vote answers and standards have changed in the mean time.

Comment: Who wrote this code you posted here? What is the license on it?

Comment: I wrote this code. It is part of the PVFMM library (see pvfmm.org). The library itself available under LGPLv3. The code posted here is available free without any restrictions. You can modify it and use it as you like; however, please cite the PVFMM library in any work that you publish.

Comment: Variable names M, N, m, n, k, tU, tS, tVT, JOBU, JOBVT, A, LDA, S, U, LDU, VT and LDVT considered harmful

Comment: Be aware that @dhairya has updated the code to fix an infinite loop condition: https://github.com/dmalhotra/pvfmm/commit/30759297f670fcdec61b3404b8b6e8f762a6a979

Answer (score 6):

[GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Singular-Value-Decomposition.html) is great for SVD.

Comment: GSL's SVD subroutine is fine, but it is really slow while computing the SVD of a M (> 800) by (> 600) matrix.

Answer (score 6):

**[Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/)** is a C++ template library to do linear algebra. It tries to provide an API that is similar to Matlab, so its pretty easy to use. It has a SVD implementation that is built upon LAPACK and BLAS. Usage is simple:

```
#include <armadillo>

// Input matrix of type float
arma::fmat inMat;

// Output matrices
arma::fmat U;
arma::fvec S;
arma::fmat V;

// Perform SVD
arma::svd(U, S, V, inMat);
```

Comment: For large matrices, using the "dc" option to [Armadillo's SVD](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#svd) can provide considerable speedups -- it enables the divide-and-conquer algorithm.  For example, arma::svd(U, S, V, inMat, "dc");