# Eigenvectors, eigenvalues fixed point calculation in C

Tags: c, fixed-point, svd, eigenvector, eigenvalue

** **Edited** **

I tried changing the mentioned Jacobi algorithm to fixed point using [libfixmath](https://code.google.com/p/libfixmath/) but I am not getting right results. What did I miss??

[edited Jacobi code](https://copy.com/CBOUb0wYIkxtWzd9)

[makefile](https://copy.com/b3XxLcKBYdiZEC6h)

---

C newbie here. I somehow got my self in the deep and i cant find my way out. If you could help that would be awesome!

The situation: I am trying to implement an ICA algorithm in C. I did so using floating point arithmetic (double, float). Now I want this code to transform it to fixed point so I can import it on an ARM microcontroller of 32 bits (thats why i cant use double, float etc).

I have found four libraries that I think can help me:

1. http:// sourceforge.net/projects/avrfix/files/
2. http:// www.dsprelated.com/showcode/40.php
3. http:// sourceforge.net/p/fixedptc/code/ci/default/tree/
4. libfixmath

I didnt use 1. 2. or 3. I am currently trying libfixmath because allmost all calculations are done with matrices.

My problem is when trying to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a covariance matrix (positive symmetic 3x3 matrix). I searched around for libs or functions that do eigendecomposition or SVD etc. but i didnt find anything.

**How to you do that sort of calculation in fixed point??** 
Are there any functions/libs that i didnt find out? Do I have to alter the eigen function that I have in floating-point (line by line converting to fixed point - i.e fix16_from_dbl() )?

My current eigen function (not mine of course i think it is from Numerical Recipes)

[jacobi.h](https://copy.com/VlN6gQ1D6tTG6URJ)

Other relevant question:
Here's [StackOverflow fixed SVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614900/fixed-point-singular-value-decomposition-in-c-c)

****Is my first question if there is anything to correct in my question please say so....dont eat me alive! :)

** Edited **

libfixmath does Cholesky[1](https://code.google.com/p/libfixmath/), wiki[2](https://copy.com/CBOUb0wYIkxtWzd9) and QR decomposition.

I tried to play with maths and produce the eigenvectors or eigenvalue of a matrix with this data (data from the above functions) but I failed.

If anyone knows how to do that then problem solved.

*Should I post it to math stack website?

[1](https://code.google.com/p/libfixmath/) http:// rosettacode.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition

[2](https://copy.com/CBOUb0wYIkxtWzd9) http:// en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#The_Cholesky.E2.80.93Banachiewicz_and_Cholesky.E2.80.93Crout_algorithms

Answer (score 1):

How about the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl)? It has a [number of functions related to eigenvalue decomposition](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Eigensystems.html#Eigensystems)

You could use something like [IQMath](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/IQmath_Library_for_C28x) in order to convert from floating-point to fixed-point.  There are also a number of answers for a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368396/how-do-i-convert-a-floating-point-c-code-to-fixed-point)

Comment: Maybe i didnt see something right but does GSL have functions for fixed point math/operations? As I saw from your proposed **gsl_eigen.h** everything is declared as double. Isn't double a floating point type?

Comment: You are right. Let me expand a bit on other alternatives that might help you.

Comment: IQMath is truly a useful tool. But in this point is giving me nothing more in this simple program of mine (i think) than the other libraries that I mentioned.